# Google One app: sharing with others, using this to make sure files are not deleted

Tags: google-account, google, accessibility

On the Google One app can I make use of feature found on the web as in the following image:

"Share with you to 5 others"

[image: share with other users]

It is saying I can share my account.

Therefore, if I create another second account, and only I know the password to the second account, and some files are deleted from the primary account, I am able to recover the files from the secondary account.

Is there a Google One feature that works this way?

If not, it wouldn't it be good if it were implemented?

Is this possible, at the moment, and, if not, how could support for this be added?

Thanks.